# TypeError: element.summernote is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, webpack, summernote

I'm working on project based on Angular, Webpack, etc. And I've faced to very interesting issue when I wanted to use [angular-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote)

It doesn't work, and gives me an error "TypeError: element.summernote is not a function". It works normally if adding libraries as script tags, without any build tool, but with Webpack it doesn't.

So, let's look at files and configs

**webpack.config.js**

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        bundle: [
            './app/app.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './public'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        root: __dirname,
        extensions: ['', '.js'],
        modulesDirectories: [
            'node_modules',
            'app'
        ],
    },
    externals: {

    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                },
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            }
        ]
    }

};
```

**app/app.js**

```
// Load libs
import angular from 'angular';
import ngRoute from 'angular-route';
import summernote from 'summernote';
import ngSummernote from 'angular-summernote/dist/angular-summernote.js';

// App
angular.module('app', [ngRoute, 'summernote'])

.config(function($routeProvider) {

    // Router
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            template: '<summernote></summernote>'
        });
});
```

I've found [github issue](https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote/issues/158), but it still has Open status.

I made some debug, checked "link" method of "summernote" directive, and logged "element" to console, it's proto object doesn't contain any jquery methods including "summernote" method. **Why? And how to make it work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like **jquery** is used on demand and not loaded before other scripts, so it doesn't expose global variable jQuery, and doesn't attach appropriate methods to elements.

The following configuration solves this problem

**webpack.config.js**

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        bundle: [
            // We tell webpack to add jquery as script tag before app script
            // It will expose global variable jQuery and init jquery methods
            'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',

            './app/app.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './public'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        root: __dirname,
        extensions: ['', '.js'],
        modulesDirectories: [
            'node_modules',
            'app'
        ],
    },
    externals: {
        // This mean that require('jquery') will refer to global var jQuery
        'jquery': 'jQuery' 
    },
    plugins: [
        // ProvidePlugin helps to recognize $ and jQuery words in code
        // And replace it with require('jquery')
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                },
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            }
        ]
    }

};
```

Hope it will be useful to clarify how **webpack** works. And please share your thoughts and comments if I missed something.

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me by adding new file with name "webpack.config.js" and paste above code in /src folder .

Comment: i am having the same problem but couldn't resolve it. Anyone can please help me out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642201/how-to-handle-two-set-of-librarys-in-your-front-end-project?noredirect=1#comment112558333_63642201