# How to handle two set of library's in your front end project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, module, madcap

[image]

I am having Angular 1.x/jQuery project where I have already loaded all front end library like jQuery.js, require.js,angular.js. Now I am planning to integrate with Madcap Documentation libraries. They are giving another set of same front-end jQuery/require js library which is a different version than the existing version of my project. How can I load the new madcap library without conflicting the existing UX library?

We have a angular-summernote on our project which throws error like

```
TypeError: element.summernote is not a function.
```

i tried jquery noConflict option like below and it doesn't work :( Any other option to try out to load the libraries?

```
<html>
<head>
      <script src="./assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script> 
    $.noConflict(true);
                 var jq = jQuery;
                 jq(document).ready(function($){        
                    jq.ajax({
                        url: '/login',
                        type: 'PUT',
                        success: function (response) {
    
                            var url = "app.min.js?v=" + response.clientGitHash;
                            jq.ajax({
                                url: url,
                                type: 'GET',
                                dataType: 'script',
                                cache: true,
                                success: function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                                    console.log("Successfully Loaded.");                   
                                    //i want to enforce the below getscript use only the default loaded jquery and not having conflict with further loading library.
                                    jq.getScript("scripts/summernote-bs4.min.js", function(data2, textStatus2, jqxhr2) {  
                                        console.log("Loading SummerNote ");
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
    </script>
    
    
     <script src="scripts/helpDoc/Default.js"></script>  // This is a vendor file from madcap which loads it versions of jquery, requiresjs etc.
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Generally you only need one version of jQuery.js unless there is a dependent plugin that uses deprecated methods or has some sort of incompatibility error. Not enough known here about versions used

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In my case, I am getting conflict for angular-summernote library. After adding this madcap library, it throws the error. Madcap try to load jquery version 1.8.3

Comment: Ok...that is an old version then. Using noConflict should work to load both if used properly. Show how you tried it

Comment: @charlietfl i have just updated my script above in the question. Kindly check. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @charlietfl any thought on my issue?

Comment: Oh I see you use `getScript()` for the summernote.js. You can't use that until getScript completes

Comment: Yes. Even i try to load after the getScripts() but still getting conflict.

Comment: I came to discuss with you in chat when you requested it but never heard anything

Comment: Yes. I tried all the option and none doesn't work. I tried to load the libraries in a different order but it doesn't work. I have tried jQuery.noConflict() method and it doesn't work. Do you have any idea why the angular-summernote throws the error and how can I safely isolate two different libraries?